# Password Dictionary Lookup

Tags: .net, dictionary, passwords

I have a .Net application which needs to implement dictionary lookup as part of the password validation process.  I can easily use a tool like NHunspell to look up passwords that are dictionary words alone.  However I cannot find a means to lookup passwords that CONTAIN a dictionary lookup word, e.g.  BOAT@123, where BOAT is the dictionary word.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tell us your *exact* requirements for an acceptable password please. What about "boatboat"? We shouldn't have to guess.